# Create a list with duplicates

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I'm implementing a procedure in my case "getDuplicatesAlphabetical" that takes a list of person objects and returns a tuple containing all the names that appear multiple times
at this..

This is what I have so far:

```
def getDuplicatesAlphabetical(listOfPersonObjects):
  l = []
  dup = []
  for person in listOfPersonObjects:
    if person not in l:
      l.append(person)
    else:
      dup.append(person)
  return sorted(dup)


getDuplicatesAlphabetical(toObjectList(['Thomas', 'Michael', 'Thomas','Susanne','Michael','Thomas','Alfred','Alfred']))
#shall output: ('Alfred', 'Michael', 'Thomas')**
```

I just do not understand what is missing.. Can somebody help me?
Regards, Mike

Comment: What is `toObjectList`? Please make sure your [mre] actually runs and reproduces your problem. Also [edit] your question to include desired output, actual output, and __full__ stack trace of any errors that occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) is for! Checking if an item exists in a set is [much cheaper](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) O(1) than checking if it exists in a list O(n). The additional advantage is that adding an element that already exists in the set doesn't actually duplicate it.

```
def getDuplicatesAlphabetical(listOfPersonObjects):
  l = set()
  dup = set()
  for person in listOfPersonObjects:
    if person not in l:
      l.add(person)
    else:
      dup.add(person)
  return sorted(list(dup))
```

Testing this, we get

```
getDuplicatesAlphabetical(toObjectList(['Thomas', 'Michael', 'Thomas','Susanne','Michael','Thomas','Alfred','Alfred']))
# Output:  ['Alfred', 'Michael', 'Thomas']
```

Another way is to count the instances of all names, and return the ones that have more than one occurrence. You can use the inbuilt `collections.Counter` for that, or do it yourself.

```
def getDuplicatesAlphabetical(listOfPersonObjects):
    counts = {}
    for person in listOfPersonObjects:
        countkey = person
        counts[countkey] = counts.get(countkey, 0) + 1
    return sorted([name for name, count in counts.items() if count > 1])
```

Remember that `dict` keys can only be immutable objects, so if `listOfPersonObjects` has mutable elements, you will have to do something like `countkey = person.name` or `countkey = person['name']`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't check to see if the item is already in `dup`.  An easy fix would be to add:

```
if person in dup:
    continue
```

or change the `else` to:

```
elif person not in dup:
    dup.append(person)
```

FWIW a much easier way to count up items (e.g. for finding duplicates) is `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def get_dupes_sorted(names):
...     return sorted(name for name, count in Counter(names).items() if count > 1)
...
>>> get_dupes_sorted(['Thomas', 'Michael', 'Thomas', 'Susanne', 'Michael', 'Thomas', 'Alfred', 'Alfred'])
['Alfred', 'Michael', 'Thomas']
```

Using `Counter` should also be faster for large data sets than using lists because it uses a dictionary internally; checking if an item is `in` a list requires scanning the entire list (so it gets slower as the list gets bigger, i.e. "linear time"), whereas locating an item in a dictionary or set takes the same amount of time (i.e. "constant time") regardless of how many other items there are.

I'm assuming that a `personObject` is either an alias for a string or is an object that correctly implements the various comparators that are needed for `in` and `sorted` to work -- if not, then that might be an additional problem!  But it's impossible to debug that without seeing your implementation of `toObjectList`.

Answer (score -1):

First remove **listOfObject()** function. It is not defined yet.
and then change the if statement like the following

```
if listOfPersonObjects.count(person)>1:
            if person in dup:
                l.append(person)
            else:
                dup.append(person)
```

Output:`['Alfred', 'Michael', 'Thomas']`

Comment: O(n^2) solution is sub-optimal. Why do you need to append to `l`? If `count > 1` then you can just append to `dup` if it isn't already there.